# Race condition in unit tests

Tags: swift, unit-testing, race-condition, xctest

I'm currently testing a number of classes that do network stuff like REST API calls, and a Realm database is mutated in the process. When I run all the different tests I have at once, race conditions appear (but of course, when I run them one by one, they all pass). How can I reliably make the tests pass?

I have tried to call the mentioned functions in a GCD block like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.function.start()
}
```

One of my tests are still failing, so I guess the above didn't work. I have enabled Thread Sanitizer and it reports, from time to time, that race conditions appear.

I can't post code, so I'm looking for conceptual solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Typically some form of dependency injection. Be it an internally exposed var to the DispatchQueue, a default argument in a function with the queue, or a constructor argument. You just need some way to pass a test queue that dispatches the event when you need to.

`DispatchQueue.main.async` will schedule the block async to the callee on the main queue and therefore isn't guarenteed by the time you make an assertion.

Example (disclaimer: I'm typing from memory so it might not compile but it gives the idea):

```
// In test code.
struct TestQueue: DispatchQueue {

    // make sure to impement other necessary protocol methods

    func async(block: () -> Void) {
        // you can even have some different behavior for when to execute the block. 
        // also you can pass XCTestExpectations to this TestQueue to be fulfilled if necessary.
        block()
    }
}

// In source code. In test, pass the Test Queue to the first argument
func doSomething(queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.main, completion: () -> Void) {
    queue.async(block: completion)
}
```

Other methods of testing async and eliminating race conditions revolve around craftily fulfilling an XCTestExpectation.

If you have access to the completion block that is eventually invoked:

```
// In source 
class Subject {

    func doSomethingAsync(completion: () -> Void) {
        ...
    }

}

// In test

func testDoSomethingAsync() {
    let subject = Subject()
    let expect = expectation(description: "does something asnyc")
    subject.doSomethingAsync {
        expect.fulfill()
    }

    wait(for: [expect], timeout: 1.0)
    // assert something here
    // or the wait may be good enough as it will fail if not fulfilled
}
```

If you don't have access to the completion block it usually means finding a way to inject or subclass a test double that you can set an XCTestExpectation on and will eventually fulfill the expectation when the async work has completed.

Comment: Thanks for the thought-out reply! I haven't had the time to check it out because of vacation, but I'll definitely do it as soon as I'm back :)